# Which preposition? The rate "for","of","between", or "from" 2000 to 2010?

Tags: prepositions

Let's say I calculate the rate the population changed from 2000 to 2010.
Is this than the growth rate "for", "of", "between", or "from" 2000 to 2010?

Answer (score 2):

Any of them would work. But if you use *between* - then you need to change "2000 to 2010" to "2000 and 2010*.

Answer (score 1):

As already answered above, all 4 forms can be used. If you use "for" or "of"  then you need to add a word like 'period' or 'interval' for full grammatical correctness, as in  **for/of the period (from) 2000 to 2010** or **for/of the interval between 2000 and 2010**. You can also avoid 'for' and 'of' and simply write **population growth rate from 2000 to 2010** or **(rate of) population change between 2000 and 2010**.